# How to delete data from excel sheet while creating and dropping table through SSIS package

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have created a package that will query SQL server and return results to excel, this package should replace existing data on the excel with new data every time it runs.
But Drop table command only clears the headings of excel table not the previous data.
Its appending new data in sheet not deleting the old data.[image]

Drop table I am using this command.

```
  Drop Table `Report`
     Go
```

Create Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `Report` (
`EmployeeID` Long,
`EmpName` LongText,
`EmpGrp` LongText
)
GO
```

Please help on this. How to delete data from table in excel.

Comment: what do you mean by in excel?

Comment: While first time I am executing this package its working perfectly fine. But I am second time running this package it appends the new data in excel sheet with the Old Data whereas I am using Drop table command to delete that sheet from excel but its deleting only header not the data

Comment: why do you drop the table and don't use truncate? and no create is needed

Comment: Then how to add new data in existing sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template file containing the sheet with the header and a File System Task copies it over the previously exported file before the Data Flow Transformation.

Maybe this solution will suit your needs: [Overwrite Excel File in SSIS: Workaround for Excel Connection Manager](http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.de/2011/11/overwrite-excel-file-in-ssis-not-using.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to use 'Script Task' in place of Drop Table to validate if the excel is already present and if yes then delete the existing excel.

`

```
(File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::DestinationExcelFilePath"].Value.ToString()))
{
    File.Delete(Dts.Variables["User::DestinationExcelFilePath"].Value.ToString());
}
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

`if

Rest all follow the same process as you are doing right now. Also please note to set DelayValidation property of Control Flow to True for the code to work as expected.